# My 2016 13" MacBook Pro's screen goes black when it is opened vertically beyond 90 degree

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I have experienced this issue today. I closed my MacBook as usual when I had something to do. Then I came back, tried to use it again. However the screen went dark when it was opened vertically beyond 90 degree.

I went on the Internet to search for this problem and tried to resetting SMC, but it did not work. How can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Ask Different. [This sounds a lot like a hardware issue unfortunately - specifically a loose display cable.](https://9to5mac.com/2019/01/22/macbook-pro-stage-light/) For MacBook models 2016 - present, the display cable is integrated into the display itself, so you will need to get the whole display replaced. Please see the attached article for further information regarding the issue. Sorry and best of luck.